# multiple selects with different where conditions and limits

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a high scores table that is slightly more complicated because scores are tracked in rounds (round 1, round 2, round 3, etc.).  Sample table:

| scoreID | roundID | userID | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 25 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 12 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 14 |
| 4 | 1 | 5 | 6 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 39 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | 23 |
| 7 | 2 | 4 | 13 |
| 8 | 2 | 5 | 26 |

There can be many more rounds, and many more users.

I would like to pull the top 3 user scores from each round. My select statement at the moment looks like this:

```
select `scores`.`score`, `users`.`username`, `scores`.`roundID` 
FROM `scores` 
INNER JOIN `users` on `users`.`user_id` = `scores`.`userID` 
ORDER BY `scores`.`score` DESC LIMIT 3;
```

However, this returns a result like so:

| score | username | roundID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 39 | joey | 2 |
| 26 | bubba | 2 |
| 25 | george | 1 |

when what I want is the top 3 scores per round:

| score | username | roundID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | george | 1 |
| 14 | bubba | 1 |
| 12 | joey | 1 |
| 39 | george | 2 |
| 26 | homey | 2 |
| 23 | joey | 2 |

How do I select the top 3 scores in each round so my result mirrors the table immediately above?

Comment: what do you want if there are ties for first, second, or third place?  for this you would use row_number or rank or dense_rank (depending how you want ties handled) in a subquery with a where condition limiting it to top <= 3 in the outer query

Comment: Good question.  Let’s assume in the event of a tie that we take a minimum of 3 scores but all the ties. Example: 29, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27.

Comment: and always three distinct scores? or you want just one or two distinct scores if that gives you >= 3 rows?

Comment: Not always 3 distinct. So long as there’s a minimum of 3 scores.

Comment: that would be rank <= 3 then; there's a nice illustration of rank vs dense_rank vs row_number at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/dense_rank/ (mariadb documentation, but that part is applicable to mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this like:

```
select score, username, roundID
from (
    select
        score, userID, roundID,
        rank() over (partition by roundID order by score desc) score_rank
    from score
) ranked_scores
inner join users on users.user_id = ranked_scores.userID 
where score_rank <= 3
order by roundID, score, username
```